# Node Request Module .Post() Convenience method and call back

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the .post() convenience method of the Javascript/Node module request. Does it accept a callback? I don't understand why it would be complaining about this:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({url: 'https://identity.api.foo/v2.0', body: JSON.stringify({
        'auth': {
            "KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials": {
                "username": "joe",
                 "apiKey": "10677bad"
                     }
        }
}), function (e, r, body) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(r);
    console.log(body);
});

one@node ~ $ node try.js 

/home/one/try.js:9
}), function (e, r, body) {
             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
one@node ~ $
```

**EDIT**: Just a follow up...I am using restler instead and I find it to be way better. - for anyone that is in the same need of a tool like this.

Comment: In the docs it looks like the function requires a named function expression

Comment: From what I saw in the docs it didn't. But I tried one anyways and I got SyntaxError: Unexpected identified for function bob(e, r, body) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the object you're passing in before the second argument (the callback);

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({url: 'https://identity.api.foo/v2.0', body: JSON.stringify({
        'auth': {
            "KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials": {
                "username": "joe",
                 "apiKey": "10677bad"
                     }
        }
  })
}, function...
```